# AdminBro with postgres and sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to find a best admin panel for NodeJS Express Postgres app.
So far the adminBro app was the nicest I found. ( Please feel free to suggest alternatives )
Is it possible to setup admin bro with Postgres DB?

Comment: Did you find any type of solution regarding admin-bro + postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [admin-bro example app](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro-example-app) we can see that it is designed to work with postgresql. So answering your question: Yes, it is possible to setup admin-bro with Postgres DB.